# Building a custom slider with CSS animations and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Hours of researching, I have drawn a blank on my targeted problem and wanted to get some help from fellow developers and also with the hope of helping anyone else with a similar problem!

I am looking to build a custom slider with different Dom elements being animated, and custom animations happening within each slide looping to the next slide until finally reaching the last slide, which will have a button to replay the loop. Starting the loop will be initialized with a click of a button.

I am building an slider animation loop similar to: https://stripe.com/checkout

Some of the elements being animated will be dependent on the following slide **e.g.(one of the elements may be needed to complete an effect on the next slide)**

*As of now I am more focused with initialing and playing through the loop to end.

I have currently a basic structure of my slide setup, and an idea within my javascript code to possibly initialize the loop but dont quite understand how to actually make it move to the next slide in a looping manner while controlling some of the elements with the CSS I have styled, via the classes I have on certain elements.

**I added the CSS just for extra information and to be a bit more concise**

**Html**

```
    <div id="main" class="site-main">
        <section id="carousel">
            <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
                <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 500px;">
                    <ul class="bxslider_simp"  >
                        <li class="bxslide page" id="bxs1">

                            <a href="#" id="anim-start"> The Trigger to Start slide</a>
                            <!-- content of the slide goes here -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="bxslide page" id="bxs2">
                                  <!-- content of the slide goes here -->
                        </li>
                               <!-- content of the slide goes here -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="bxslide page" id="bxs4">
                                   <!-- content of the slide goes here -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="bxslide page" id="bxs5">
                                    <!-- content of the slide goes here -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="bxslide page" id="bxs6">
                                   <!-- content of the slide goes here -->
                        </li>
                        <li class="bxslide page" id="bxs7">
                              <!-- content of the slide goes here -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#carousel').animationLoop();
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
#bxs1 .animation class here {
    -moz-animation-name:fade-down;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:1;
-moz-animation-direction:normal;
}

@-moz-keyframes fade-down {
0% {
-moz-transform:translateY(-70px);
        opacity:0;
}
100% {
-moz-transform:translateY(0);
      opacity:0.9;
}
}
```

**application.js**

```
  (function( $ ) {


//gloabl definitions
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;


//gloabl definitions for animation loop
var startTrigger = document.getElementById('anim-start');

var slide1 = document.getElementById('bxs1');
var slide2 = document.getElementById('bxs2');

// startTrigger.addEventListener("animationstart", MoveSlides, false);

//core plugin features & call
$.fn.animationLoop = function(options) {

    //Animation Loop Logic

    function MoveSlides(options) {

        if(startTrigger) {

            requestAnimationFrame(function() {

                options.slide1++;
                options.slide2++;
                MoveSlides();
            });
        }
    }


};

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check Twitter Bootstrap carousel support for basic looping of carousel images. Can be tweaked to add buttons on slides you want:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').carousel();
interval: 5000
});
</script>

<div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation     -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
<img class="nivo-main-image" src="<location of image1>" style="display: inline; height: auto; width: 1286px;"> 
  <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
    <p>Caption text here</p>
  </div> -->
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img class="nivo-main-image" src="<location of image1>" style="display: inline; height: auto; width: 1286px;"> 
  <!-- <div class="carousel-caption">
    <p>Caption text here</p>
  </div> -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```